# Why is 0/1 Knapsack not part of Greedy Algorithm but Fractional Knapsack is?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

I don't get it. I really don't. Greedy Algorithm for me, only cares about :

1. Dividing a problem into **stages**[sub problems]
2. **Maximizing/Minimizing or **Optimizing output in each stage**** irrespective of later stages or anything else.

Even the 0/1 Knapsack Problem is solved using the same theory.

1. **Stages** become various items to fill
2. **Optimizing output in each stage** becomes picking the item providing most profit first and then picking the next item providing most profit and so on.

It's the same approach that we are following on both Knapsack problems. The only difference is :

1. **In Fractional Knapsack** : we maximize profit by picking the item providing most PROFIT/WEIGHT. Why? Because items can be divided
2. **In 0/1 Knapsack** : we maximize profit by simply picking the item providing most profit. Since items cannot be divided, we don't think about calculating profit/weight as it makes no difference.

They both should fall under Greedy Algorithm.
I'm just not able to understand where does concept of Dynamic Programming arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy algorithms are not about dividing the problem and solving it in parts.

It is in fact DP or backtracking. In Greedy we choose the best possible option that we have at the moment and pick that and compute for the rest. Best example for this is Dijkstra.

In 0/1 we don't know which item will give us the maximum weight, so we have to try all the items. In order to avoid computing the same input space again and again, we store the intermediate result and that's why it falls under DP.

In partial knapsack, we basically take the item which will give us the best weight at the moment, pick that and compute for the remaining of the weight.